# Checkbutton on tkinter retains it's value no matter what

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get the value from Checkbutton on tkinter but it retains the original value. I have tried what people say on countless forums including this one but nothing works, it just retains the value i give it with `var.set(True)` or `var.set(False)`. This chechbutton is on a pop up window btw, but it's not global, it's just defined on said window. this is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

var = tk.BooleanVar()
var.set(False)
startup = tk.Checkbutton(root, variable=var, onvalue=True, offvalue=False , text = "test")
```

when ver i use `var.get()` i get the initial value. help me plz :( Thanks in advice.

Comment: How do you know `var.get()` doesn't work? Your code never calls `var.get()`. Please provide a _complete_ [mcve]. When I add enough code to print the value on a button click, it always prints the correct value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason is because Checkbutton requires a callback function to change the state of the button.

```
def toggle(button):
    if button.get() is True:
        button.set(True)
    else:
        button.set(False)
```

The you would use the callback function in the instantiation of the Checkbutton

```
startup = tk.Checkbutton(root, variable=var, text = "test",
            command=lambda button=var: toggle(button))
```

Comment: _"Checkbutton requires a callback function to change the state of the button"_ - that is not true.

Comment: I accept that I am wrong that Checkbutton requires a callback function. However for the state of the button to be changed with a click event, is the callback function needed then?

Comment: No, a callback is not needed at all for a Checkbutton to function properly.

Comment: but it worked just fine after i did a little adjustment :(

Comment: @savyexe, Bryan Oakley is right to say that you don't need a callback function to change the state of a Checkbutton. I think your question was ill-posed because he interpreted it as saying that you can't read the value when it is changed. What you wanted was to toggle the value and have it reflected visually. That is what I interpreted your question as.